# How to avoid the error "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in Playwright

Tags: playwright

This problem is very difficult to reproduce in the playground, so I try to describe it in words. When I run the test I receive the error
[image]

If I add the empty line in the test for example
[image]

Everything works fine.

Do you have any ideas about what I do wrong?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] as [text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Thanks.